# Specify logging.properties in embedded Glassfish with maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin

Tags: logging, glassfish-embedded, maven-glassfish-plugin

I use a project template containing a Maven configuration for an embedded Glassfish (using the maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin). I need to enable logging, but I do not even know which logging engine is enabled in the Glassfish (since I did not create the template).

The template uses *slf4j-log4j12* as a dependency, but I am not sure if slf4j or java.util.logging does the actual logging. Therefore I created two logging files, one `logging.properties` and one `log4j.properties` and put them both to `src/main/resources` and `/src/main/resources/META-INF`, which both does not seem to work.

I added `java.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties` to the Maven Glassfish system properties (also for log4j), and also this did not work out. I checked, that the properties files are in the JAR file.

How can I determine which backend is responsible for logging?

**How can I specify a logging configuration for embedded Glassfish using the Maven embedded Glassfish plugin?**

Currently I get logging output at level INFO on default out. I guess this is the default setting.

Comment: I'm currently trying to work how to do the same thing, did you ever find a solution? I've tried the following config for the plugin but it is ignored, <systemProperties>
                        <property>java.util.logging.config.file=glassfish/glassfish-logging.properties</property>
                    </systemProperties>