# maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin not work with logback

Tags: java, glassfish-3, logback, glassfish-embedded

I am encountering a problem when using maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin(3.1.2.2) with logback that the configuration of logback is NOT used in embedded glassfish.

And, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21645652/configure-glassfish-embedded-server-with-logback-logging) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16335091/specify-logging-properties-in-embedded-glassfish-with-maven-embedded-glassfish-p) are similar posts with NO solution found.
Anyone can help?
This is my pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <!-- JEE -->
    <jee.version>6.0</jee.version>

    <!-- logger -->
    <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>

    <!-- maven plugin -->
    <maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin.version>3.1.2.2</maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- JEE -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jee.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- logger -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.embedded</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <app>target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</app>
                <port>8080</port>
                <ports>
                    <https-listener>8181</https-listener>
                </ports>
                <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
                <contextRoot>/</contextRoot>
                <autoDelete>true</autoDelete>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```